# Powershell Disable Inactive Computers Script Error

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that is supposed to look at any computer object in active directory and disable any object showing a lastlogon 90days or older. This will also update the accounts description to "Disabled due to inactivity DATE" and send an email of accounts disabled.

I am receiving the below error. Any help is greatly appreciated. I have a lot to learn.

```
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADComputer] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At C:\Scripts\DisableInactiveComputers.ps1:58 char:1
+ $Info += "$UpdateInformation - $Date"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Code:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
[Parameter( Mandatory=$false)]
[int]$TimeFrame = 90,

[Parameter( Mandatory=$false)] 
[string]$UpdateInformation = "Disabled due to inactivity", 
 
[Parameter( Mandatory=$false)] 
[switch]$Remediate, 
 
[Parameter( Mandatory=$false)] 
[string]$LogName = "ComputerLogFile.txt", 
 
[Parameter( Mandatory=$false)] 
[string]$ExclusionsPath = "C:\Scripts\ComputerExclusions.txt", 
 
[Parameter( Mandatory=$false)] 
[string]$TriggeredPath = ".\Computertriggered.csv" 
 ) 

$Date = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"
$LogDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyy MMM d - HH:mm:ss tt"
$myDir = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$LogPath = "$myDir\$LogName"
$TriggeredPath = "$myDir\$TriggeredPath"
$Report = New-Object PSObject
$TriggeredComputers = @()
$Exclusions = Get-Content $ExclusionsPath
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString 'supernotsecretpassword' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("email@somewhere.com", $secpasswd)
$smtpServer="smtp.office365.com"
$from = "<email@somewhere.com>"
$emailaddress = "someotheremail@somewhere.com"  

Import-Module ActiveDirectory


$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Properties LastLogonDate,SamAccountName -Filter {Enabled -eq $true}


Function Write-LogFile {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
[Parameter( Position=0,Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$LogData
)
"$Date - $LogData" | Out-file -FilePath $LogPath -Append
}


foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
if ($Exclusions -notcontains $Computer.Name) {
if ($Computer.LastLogonDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$TimeFrame) -AND $Computer.LastLogonDate -ne $null) {
if ($Remediate) {
if ($UpdateInformation -ne $null) {
$Info = Get-ADComputer $Computer.Name -Properties info | Where-Object {$info}
$Info += "$UpdateInformation - $Date"
try {
Set-ADComputer $Computer.Name -Description "$Info" -ErrorAction Stop
Write-LogFile -LogData "Successfully set Info field for $($Computer.Name). New Info: $Info"
}
catch {
Write-LogFile -LogData "Error - Failed to set Info field for $($Computer.Name) - $"
}
}
try {
Disable-ADAccount -Identity $Computer.Name -ErrorAction Stop
Write-LogFile -LogData "$($Computer.Name) successfully disabled"
}
catch {
Write-LogFile -LogData "Error - Failed to disable AD Account $($Computer.Name)"
}
}
$TriggeredComputers += $Computer | Select Name,LastLogonDate,SamAccountName
}
}
}
$TriggeredComputers | Format-Table
$TriggeredComputers | Export-Csv $TriggeredPath -NoTypeInformation

$subject="120 Day Inactive Computer Account(s) Disabled"
$csvHTML = Import-Csv C:\Scripts\Computertriggered.csv | ConvertTo-Html
$body = @"
The following computer accounts have been disabled.
"@ + ($csvHTML[5..($csvHTML.length-2)] | Out-String)
Send-Mailmessage -smtpServer $smtpServer -Credential $cred -from $from -to $emailaddress -subject $subject -body $body -bodyasHTML -UseSSL
```

Have a similar script for users accounts that works flawlessly and is almost the exact same.

Answer (score 0):

The error is, I guess, in the line before (line 67):

```
$Info = $Info = Get-ADComputer $Computer.Name -Properties info | Where-Object {$info}
```

Its a little hard to determine what you are after, but if its appending something to the description (as indicated by lines 58 and 60) I think you probably would be best served with:

```
$Info = (Get-ADComputer $Computer.Name -properties $description).description
```

This will ensure that what you get back is a single string which can be appended with the date etc. in the next line.